# Functions Query

Tags: c, function

I'm not getting the desired output in the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int roman(int,int,char);
int main()
{
    int yr;
    printf("Please enter a year: ");
    scanf("%d",&yr);
    yr =  roman(yr,1000,'m');  
    yr =  roman(yr,900,'cm');
    yr =  roman(yr,500,'d');
    yr =  roman(yr,400,'cd');
    yr =  roman(yr,100,'c');
    yr =  roman(yr,90,'xc');
    yr =  roman(yr,50,'l');
    yr =  roman(yr,40,'xl');
    yr =  roman(yr,10,'x');
    yr =  roman(yr,9,'ix');
    yr =  roman(yr,5,'v');
    yr =  roman(yr,4,'iv');
    yr =  roman(yr,1,'i');
    return 0;
}
int roman(int yr,int k, char m)
{
    int j,i;
    j = yr/k;
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
        printf("%c",m);
    return (yr-k*j);
}
```

---

Sample Output:

Please enter a year: 144
clv

Please enter a year: 9
x

---

Why is this happening, i want 144 to be cxliv and 9 to be ix.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Statements are executed in sequence, what are you doing?

Comment: `I'm not getting the desired output in the following program` So what? What's your *desired output*?

Comment: Please step through your program with a debugger. This will help you to find errors quickly.

Comment: You are working with characters, but, for example, `'cm'` is not a single character, but two. You should work with strings instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment, a `char` can only store a single character. For example, you cannot pass `cm` as a single character to `roman()`. Instead you should pass a pointer to a string to `roman()` and modify the `printf()` accordingly:

```
int roman(int, int, char*);
int main()
{
    [...]
    yr = roman(yr, 1000, "m");
    yr = roman(yr, 900, "cm");
    [...]
}
int roman(int yr, int k, char* m)
{
    int j,i;
    j = yr/k;
    for(i=1; i<=j; i++)
        printf("%s", m);
    return (yr-k*j);
}
```

Maybe there are more problems, but this solves at least one of them.